# Using PCM1807 with a microphone

Tags: audio, adc, microphone

I'm new here and I trying to figure out how to work with an ADC. I've read a lot of stuff and I believe that an AD converter it's "very simple" to use. What I mean: Plug the analog source to one side and get the digital source on the other side. However, this is theory - it's not that simple in real life.

What I'm trying to do is, use the PCM1807 (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm1807.pdf) to get signals from a cardioid microphone.

I was trying to figure out how to make the connections of page 25, but what I didn't understand is do I need that MCU, that AND port with MASK and PLL, and that DSP or AUDIO PROCESSOR to make it work?

Sorry for the newbie question!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your application. You have two important matters to keep in mind: **what you are going to do with that digital signal** and **how you are going to configure the ADC/retrieve data from ADC**.

The DSP exists there to fulfill that first bit ("you have a digital signal - so what?"). You most likely want to process and interpret that signal in your application. The DSP is a *typical application component*.

The ADC you have presented (PCM1807) has a SPI interface and a MCU should be used for the necessary ADC configurations and commands - thorough datasheet reading is needed here. But now that you have a MCU there, the DSP existence depends on your desired application - you could be doing signal processing in that very same MCU, for example. This depends of course on your MCU capabilities.

The PLL is necessary as system clock for the proper signal sampling, as it needs to output a signal with frequency that is multiple (x256, x384 or x512) of sampling frequency.

Considering you are just starting out with ADCs (and 24 bits is just slightly an overkill), may I suggest a simpler chip? Something like [MAX11647](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX11646-MAX11647.pdf) has only 10 bits, 94.4 kHz sampling frequency, but has an overall simpler application circuit.